# position:absolute и flexbox

Tags: html, css

Если `position:absolute;` вырывает блок из потока документа, то это значит, что свойства (например: `justify-content:center;`) заданные его родителю (укажем у родителя `position:relative;`) не будут работать на нем?

Comment: вы можете просто попробовать

Comment: Это да, я попробовал у меня не работает, просто может я ошибся где и здесь бы мне сказали что можно и показали верное решение

Comment: приведите ваш код, укажите что именно не работает, а так же ожидаемое поведение

Comment: http://codepen.io/Fess/pen/QyZXjd?editors=1100 
Я понял что свойства флекс боксов не работают на position:absolute; но не подскажите как правильно в таком случии центрировать текст по горизонтали и вертикали?, мой вариант вот

Comment: Добавьте сам код в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал вам [пример](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVQJgY) внимательно посмотрите как это можно реализовать

[Документация W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) на английском

[4.1. Absolutely-Positioned Flex Children](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#abspos-items)

Также ответил вам в вашем [другом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490032/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content1,
.content2 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.content1 {
  background-color: #008000;
}
.content1 .block1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.content2 {
  background-color: #ffc0cb;
}
.content2 .absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.content2 .absolute .block2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="content1">
  <div class="block1"></div>
</div>
<div class="content2">
  <div class="absolute">
    <div class="block2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490032/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/490206#490206 ответ который вы дали тут меня полностью устроил, спасибо вам

Comment: Рад что помог, следующий раз старайтесь не дублировать вопрос и старайтесь полностью описать вопрос с примерами.