# Разместить текст в центре изображения

Tags: html, css

Разметка сделана с использованием `flexbox`, требуется разместить небольшой текст на картинке посередине, изображение задается не через `CSS`, а с помощью тега `img`. Картинка адаптивна.

Я сам сделал так, меня устроил бы и такой результат, но для того чтобы сделать горизонтальное центрирование мне надо установить `width:100%;`, а когда я к блокам добавляю `padding` по бокам, то происходит конфликт и появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block1">
     <div class="absolute-test"><p> left-block</p></div>
        <img src="https://psv4.vk.me/c414118/u112479091/docs/b2bc3bcffd63/black.jpg?extra=2C4lMpqBZzRRZVnloHrq3VpNpBu_KrYYGCgCrppMf7isOEl6G-gbopaFJsDsQtToMbt2-w7w1NTdrRgJQrGpQK8bXVjLwFUgWpbg-Gbej9u4LKgGbQ" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
     <div class="absolute-test"> <p>right-block</p></div>
      <img src="https://psv4.vk.me/c414118/u112479091/docs/b2bc3bcffd63/black.jpg?extra=2C4lMpqBZzRRZVnloHrq3VpNpBu_KrYYGCgCrppMf7isOEl6G-gbopaFJsDsQtToMbt2-w7w1NTdrRgJQrGpQK8bXVjLwFUgWpbg-Gbej9u4LKgGbQ" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container{
    display: flex;  
}
.block1{
    position: relative;
    width:50%;
    background:red;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:5px;
}
.block2{
    position: relative;
    width:50%;
    background:blue;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.img-responsive{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}
.absolute-test{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 35%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Fess/pen/QyZXjd?editors=1100

Comment: Так добавьте `overflow: hidden;` и не будет полосы прокрутки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не могли бы еще подсказать может существует более удобный способ вертикального центрирования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Поддержка FlexBox [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.container .block1,
.container .block2 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  min-width: 320px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.container .block1 .text,
.container .block2 .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .block1 .text p,
.container .block2 .text p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.container .block1 .img-responsive,
.container .block2 .img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block1">
      <div class="text"><p>left-block</p></div>
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/640/480/any/1" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <div class="text"><p>right-block</p></div>
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/640/480/any/2" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```