# Как правильно поставить CSS стили, что бы блоки не перекрывали друг друга?

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

Скажите пожалуйста, я сейчас хочу вставить прелодер в своём проекте, но не на всю страницу, а на отдельные элементы.
Должно срабатывать как на картинке.
[image: прелодер для элемента]

Здесь худо бедно работает.
Дальше у меня на странице три блока один под другим.
Пример.

```
<div>
<Элемент-№1></Элемент-№1>
<Элемент-№2></Элемент-№2>
<Элемент-№3></Элемент-№3>
</div>
```

Когда я открываю редактор блок ниже смещается вниз
[image: Открытый редактор]

Но когда я добавляю прелодер, он размещается ниже области, которую требуется скрыть.
Что бы от этого избавиться, можно поставить position: absolut на родительский блок, но у меня блоки стоящие ниже перестают менять своё положение.

Пример opacity прелодера  0.5 что бы видно было.
[image: Наложение блоков один на другой]

Как мне можно решить эту проблему ?

Comment: Позиционировать нужно относительно сами блоки а прелоадер абсолютно родителя.

Comment: Спасибо большое (и ответу ниже. Как ответ на ответ написать ?...). Я уже грешным делом в js лезть хотел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так как вариант

```css
.grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center
}

img {
  width: 100%
}

.img__wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.preloader {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2x solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <figure>
    <p class="img__wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200/?blur" alt="" />
      <span class="preloader"></span>
    </p>
    <figcaption>текст</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <p class="img__wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200/?blur" alt="" />
      <span class="preloader"></span>
    </p>
    <figcaption>текст</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <p class="img__wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200/?blur" alt="" />
      <span class="preloader"></span>
    </p>
    <figcaption>текст</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. 
Мне подсказали ещё один вариант.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489980/positionabsolute-%D0%B8-flexbox

Единственное хотелось бы добавить. Я когда либо grid либо flex поставил, заметил, что при открытии консоли, размер прелодера тоже начал изменяться(принтскрин не могу прицепить к сожалению), а на мобильных приложениях это может проявиться.
Добавил свойство position: sticky и проблема исчезла.

Comment: Это был пример, никак не полноценное решение. Все решения нужно адаптировать под себя.

Comment: Ну да. И очень крутой пример. Sticky это как раз адаптация. У меня родительский элемент <slot> для него понадобилось.
У меня структура 
<shadow-root>
<p><slot name="any"></p>
  </shadow-root>
<custom-component name ='any'> 
content
</custom-component>
И стили я применял к слоту. А подключается к нему три разных варианта редактора(слайдер, текст, текст-слайдер)